How to Enable and Configure Ceph Dashboard for MicroCeph Cluster on Microk8s?
I set up a Ceph cluster using MicroCeph inside a MicroK8s cluster and need help accessing the Ceph dashboard.

I followed the guide at HowTo setup MicroK8s with (Micro)Ceph storage
The cluster shows a status of health: HEALTH_OK

I've enabled the dashboard with: sudo microceph.ceph mgr module enable dashboard. However, when I try to access the dashboard via the default port (8080 for HTTP or 8443 for HTTPS), I get no response, indicating that the service is unavailable.
I also read Ceph Dashboard, and it mentions:

If you have installed ceph-mgr-dashboard from distribution packages, the package management system should take care of installing all required dependencies.

However, there's no specific guidance on using ceph-mgr-dashboard with a MicroCeph cluster. How do I set up the Ceph dashboard for a MicroCeph cluster installed on Microk8s?

What does sudo microceph.ceph mgr services show you after you enabled the dashboard? That would be the URL and port to connect to. But I'm not sure if microceph offers a dashboard and how to access it. I've tested microceph a while ago but I can't recall if I even tried accessing a dashboard. The microceph docs don't even mention any dashboard expect the Prometheus Dashboard.

sudo microceph.ceph mgr services returns {}. I am pivoting to rook.
